# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'out_dir'

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script to download(ScanNet data) but this error arises and I don't know what to do !
Error message:

```
C:\Users\youss>python download-scannet.py --out_dir C:\Users\youss\scannet --tf_semantic
By pressing any key to continue you confirm that you have agreed to the ScanNet terms of use as described 
a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\youss\download-scannet.py", line 232, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "C:\Users\youss\download-scannet.py", line 160, in main
    out_dir_scans = os.path.join(args.out_dir, 'scans')
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'out_dir'
```

lines 160,161,162:

```
  out_dir_scans = os.path.join(args.out_dir, 'scans')
  out_dir_test_scans = os.path.join(args.out_dir, 'scans_test')
  out_dir_tasks = os.path.join(args.out_dir, 'tasks')
```

I am using urllib.request

Comment: The code appears to simply be broken. If this isn't your code, contact the original developer. They appear to have a bug in their command line argument parsing where they didn't anticipate an argument being missed. You could also find where they're using `ArgumentParser` and find out why the `out_dir` argument isn't be handled.

Comment: ```parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Downloads ScanNet public data release.')
   parser.add_argument('--o', '--out_dir', required=True,  help='directory in which to download')``` this is where they are using Argumentparser

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `parser.add_argument('--out_dir', '-o',  required=True,  help='directory in which to download')`. I think the `--o` is the mistake. They've called the argument `o` as a result.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it worked !! thanks very muuuuuuuch